# why does "constants.pm" work, but "test.pm" does not?

Tags: perl, variables, initialization, perl-module, subroutine

Why does `constants.pm` work where `test.pm` does not?

constants.pm

```
package constants;

use strict;
use Exporter;
use vars qw($VERSION @ISA @EXPORT);

$VERSION     = 1.00;
@ISA         = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT      = qw(
                  $TESTVAR
                  $ABOUT_PAGE
                  $ADMIN_PAGE
                  $HELP_PAGE
                  $HOME_PAGE
                  $NEWPROWLER_PAGE
                  $PICS_PAGE
                  $PREY_PAGE
                  $PROFILE_PAGE
                  $SEARCH_PAGE
                  $SEXT_PAGE
                  $STATS_PAGE
                  $SUBSCRIPTION_PAGE
                  $TERMS_PAGE

                  $ADMIN_BAN_USER_PAGE
                  $ADMIN_CONFIG_PAGE
                  $ADMIN_EDIT_ABOUT_PAGE
                  $ADMIN_EDIT_HELP_PAGE
                  $ADMIN_EDIT_HOME_PAGE
                  $ADMIN_EDIT_THEMES_PAGE
                  $ADMIN_EDIT_USERS_PAGE

                  $STATS_BIO_PAGE
                  $STATS_DESC_PAGE
                  $STATS_LOC_PAGE
                  $STATS_PASS_PAGE
                  $STATS_SUB_PAGE
                  $STATS_THEME_PAGE
                  $STATS_VITALS_PAGE

                  $SEXT_INBOX_PAGE
                  $SEXT_NEWMSG_PAGE
                  $SEXT_SENT_PAGE
                  $SEXT_SHOWMSG_PAGE
                  $SEXT_TRASH_PAGE

                  $PICS_STD
                  $PICS_UPLOAD_PAGE

                  $END_OF_TIME
                 );

#############
# MAIN PAGES
#############
our $ABOUT_PAGE = "a"; # was about
our $ADMIN_PAGE = "A"; # was admin
our $HELP_PAGE = "h"; # was help
our $HOME_PAGE = "H"; # was ""
our $NEWPROWLER_PAGE = "N"; # was never anything, this is an "oops, forgot this one lol".
our $PICS_PAGE = "i"; # was photos
our $PREY_PAGE = "p"; # was friends
our $PROFILE_PAGE = "P"; # was profile
our $SEARCH_PAGE = "s"; # was search
our $SEXT_PAGE = "m"; # was msgs
our $STATS_PAGE = "S"; # was stats
our $SUBSCRIPTION_PAGE = "M"; # M for Membership, and because "s" and "S" are taken (was sub)
our $TERMS_PAGE  = "t"; # was never anything, another oh i forgot that one, too grr

#############
# ADMIN PAGES
#############
our $ADMIN_BAN_USER_PAGE = "b"; # was bu
our $ADMIN_CONFIG_PAGE = "c"; # was cfg
our $ADMIN_EDIT_ABOUT_PAGE = "a"; # was ab
our $ADMIN_EDIT_HELP_PAGE = "h"; # was ehe
our $ADMIN_EDIT_HOME_PAGE = "H"; # was eho
our $ADMIN_EDIT_THEMES_PAGE = "t"; # was eth
our $ADMIN_EDIT_USERS_PAGE = "u"; # was eu

#############
# USER SETTINGS PAGES
#############
our $STATS_BIO_PAGE = "b";
our $STATS_DESC_PAGE = "d";
our $STATS_LOC_PAGE = "L";
our $STATS_PASS_PAGE = "p";
our $STATS_SUB_PAGE = "s";
our $STATS_THEME_PAGE = "t";
our $STATS_VITALS_PAGE = "v";

#############
# SEXTING PAGES
#############
our $SEXT_INBOX_PAGE = "i";
our $SEXT_NEWMSG_PAGE = "c";
our $SEXT_SENT_PAGE = "s";
our $SEXT_SHOWMSG_PAGE = "S";
our $SEXT_TRASH_PAGE = "t";

#############
# PIC PAGES
#############
our $PICS_STD = "s";
our $PICS_UPLOAD_PAGE = "u";

#############
# MISC CONSTANTS
#############
our $END_OF_TIME = "Thu, 31-Dec-2037 11:59:59";

our $TESTVAR = init_test();

sub init_test {
  return "bugger!";
}

1;
```

test.pm

```
package test;

use strict;
use Exporter;
use vars qw($VERSION @ISA @EXPORT);

$VERSION     = 1.00;
@ISA         = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT      = qw(
                  $TESTVAR
                 );

our $TESTVAR = "a";

1;
```

and now test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl.exe

use strict;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

use constants;

print "content-type: text/plain\n\n";
print $TESTVAR;

exit 1;
```

change `use constants;` to `use test;` and you will see what I mean.  `constants.pm` works just fine.  `test.pm` says I must be explicit when trying to `print $TESTVAR`.  I just don't get it.

Comment: Probably catching another module named `test.pm`

Comment: or the standard Test.pm.  after the `use test;` put `BEGIN { print $INC{"test.pm"} } ` and you will see which test.pm it is finding.

Comment: ok, i changed test.pm to testy.pm and package test to package testy.

Comment: it works just fine now.  but that's weird.  because, I have another file - cookies.pm.  is there another cookies.pm i'm not aware of, then?  cuz the same issue is happening with that file....it's why i posted this in the first place - i just really simplified it...

Comment: seems there is a "cookies.pm" file.  drat.  now i gotta rename that.  tyvm for the help.  VERY useful.

Comment: I've been tripped up on `config` as well I think :)

Comment: oh ya?  fabulous.

i renamed cookies.pm to chef.pm